# how to send signup values like(email and password) into login page in website using firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

First I have created the signup page it contains the fields like email and password . After registering ,  user needs to login with the same signup credentials. My problem is how to pass the signup credentials into login page in website .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth

This holds the details of the process:

```
 firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

then

```
 firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```